# Switch between 2 voltages

Tags: voltage, mosfet, switches

I want to switch between two input voltages separately. How can I do ig with a MOSFET or other things?

[image]

Comment: Define all input power sources and expected load voltages and currents

Comment: From what you described load1 is always connected to the the 5V source and you only control load2 which can be simply implemented by a switch such as NMOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to switch between inputs voltage separately. How can I do this
> by MOSFET or other things?*

Maybe use a power-path controller like this device (for switching between 2 input voltages): -

[image]

There are plenty to choose from found [here](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11029#/p165=%7C2&p5573=0%7C5). I expect TI and others will have similar products. Basically it's two MOSFETs and some analogue circuitry that is used to switch the output from the primary power source to the secondary power source when the primary voltage drops below a certain value (determined by the resistors on the EN1 line).

You can do it with MOSFETs and some op-amps if you really wanted to. The ideal diodes shown in the picture are representing the bulk diode inside a P-channel MOSFET. If you want to build something like this from scratch. Here's the general idea: -

[image]

The chip in question controls two p-channel MOSFETs.

If you just want a simple on-off load controller then this from TI seems suitable: -

[image]

Comment: thank you for reply .  In first image , can i send  OUT2 to other load ?

Comment: Doesn't that contradict what your image shows in your question? The LTC4415 is for controlling your load 2 and, it seems to me that your load 1 is permanently connected to 5 volts.

Comment: OP seems to want to use the 5 V source to switch off and on the 4 V circuit. I suspect s/he has been overenthusiastic in accepting the answer.

Comment: I deleted a comment which, while true enough, would not have helped the target demographic, and may have caused "issues". | I note that in this case the specification was clear - just not what the OP intended. Dealing with clear well defined questions which are not actually what is wanted is "difficult".